# Validation problem while deploying Wiremock to Weblogic as a war

Tags: java, weblogic, war, weblogic12c, wiremock

I need to deploy Wiremock as a WAR to Weblogic 12.2.1.2 but during the deployment I get the a long exception.
I use `web.xml` file from the [sample-war project](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/blob/master/sample-war/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) from git.

**In my pom.xml I only use the following dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
    <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I can deploy my WAR to Tomcat 9.x and everything works fine.
But I need to use Weblogic and the same WAR does not work there. This is the beginning of the long exception I get:

```
####<oct 16, 2018, 10:03:26,646 DU CEST> <Error> <Munger> <mylinux> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <00dcc5b7-e294-4d36-943a-2d6d188fdd23-00000013> <1539720206646> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-2156200> <Unable to load descriptor /home/user/servers/oracle/weblogic/12.2.1.2.0/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/.appmergegen_1539720205648_wire-mock-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/web.xml of module wire-mock-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war. The error is weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND
  <7:11> problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4b: Element not allowed: description@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee in element listener@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.evaluateResults(MarshallerFactory.java:245)
at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.evaluateResults(MarshallerFactory.java:231)
at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:155)
at weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptor(BasicDescriptorManager.java:345)
at weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptor(BasicDescriptorManager.java:307)
at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.getDescriptorBeanFromReader(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:870)
at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.createDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:445)
at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBeanWithoutPlan(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:832)
at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:841)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppDescriptor.getWebAppBean(WebAppDescriptor.java:145)
at weblogic.servlet.utils.WarUtils.getWebAppBean(WarUtils.java:201)
at weblogic.servlet.tools.WARModule.loadDescriptors(WARModule.java:451)
at weblogic.servlet.tools.WARModule.merge(WARModule.java:520)
at weblogic.application.compiler.ToolsModuleWrapper.merge(ToolsModuleWrapper.java:96)
at weblogic.application.utils.CustomModuleManager.merge(CustomModuleManager.java:78)
at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.SingleModuleMergeFlow.proecessModule(SingleModuleMergeFlow.java:27)
at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.SingleModuleFlow.compile(SingleModuleFlow.java:64)
at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:70)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
```

I have checked the mentioned `web.xm` file but this totally okay. I have tried to use `web.xml v3.0` and `3.1` as well. Both of them not working.
It seems that the real problem is not with web.xml file. It comes from listener: `com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.servlet.WireMockWebContextListener`

Is there any idea what is wrong here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following steps need to be performed in order to have a working WAR file with WireMock 2.19.0:

**Issue (1)**:

Element not allowed:
    description@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee in element
    listener@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee

Solution: Remove `description` tag from the `listener` section of the `web.xml` file.

**Issue (2)**:

java.lang.NullPointerException at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.ServletContextFileSource.getRootFile(ServletContextFileSource.java:35)

Solution 1: Weblogic admin console > Domain > Web Applications > click the checkbox "Archived Real Path Enabled"

Solution 2: add `weblogic.xml` file to `WEB_INF` dirrectory, content:

```
<weblogic-web-app>
    <container-descriptor>
        <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

**Issue (3)**:

Classpath conflicts

Add `prefer-application-packages` to `WEB_INF/weblogic.xml` file:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.google.common.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.google.thirdparty.*</package-name>
    <package-name>net.minidev.json.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

**Issue (4)**:

Change the mapping URL of the `WireMockHandlerDispatchingServlet`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>wiremock-mock-service-handler-servlet</servlet-name>
    ...
    <init-param>
        <param-name>mappedUnder</param-name>
        <param-value>/mapping</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>wiremock-mock-service-handler-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mapping/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Issue (5)**:

Exclude Jetty related dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
    <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

**+1**

Remove WireMock admin service.

Delete `wiremock-admin-handler-servlet` servlet and its `servlet-mapping` configuration from `WEB_INF/weblogic.xml` file.

With steps above you can build a WAR which is deployable to Weblogic 12.2.x server.